# Trigger displayed items with a checkbox and a boolean attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

The setup:

```
ember new shop                                                              
cd shop
ember install:addon ember-cli-scaffold
ember generate scaffold product name:string available:boolean
ember generate adapter product
```

**app/adapters/product.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

**app/models/product.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  available: DS.attr('boolean')
});

Product.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: 'Orange',
      available: true
   }, {
     id: "2",
     name: 'Apple',
     available: false
    }, {
      id: "3",
      name: 'Banana',
      available: true
  }
]});

export default Product;
```

This will result in the following http://localhost:4200/products page:

[image: Screenshot of the product index]

**Problem/Question**

I'd like to add an *available* checkbox on top of http://localhost:4200/products which triggers the displayed products. If checked only available products are displayed. If unchecked only unavailable products.

How can I do this? What is the best/cleanest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ember g controller products/index`

**app/controller/products/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    products: function(){
      var model = this.get('model');
      var displayAvailable = this.get('displayAvailable') || false;
      return model.filterBy('available', displayAvailable);
    }.property('displayAvailable')
});
```

**app/template/products/index.hbs** (the first 25 lines)

```
<h1>Products list</h1>

<p>
  {{link-to "New Product" "products.new" }}
</p>

{{input type="checkbox" checked=displayAvailable }} Display Available Products

{{#if products.length}}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Name
        </th>
        <th>
          Available
        </th>
        <th colspan="3">
          Actions
        </th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       {{#each product in products}}
```

[image]